# Genymotion "The connection to the virtual device has been lost.

Tags: android-emulator, archlinux

I have just recently installed Genymotion and VirtualBox on Solus and when I start a virtual device y I get this error:

> The connection to the virtual device has been lost.
>
> Please restart the virtual device.

When I start the machine the screen loads but it's all in black and then I get that error.

I googled that and I found that I must reconfigure de Host-only network adapter but unfortunatly it didn't resolve the problem.
I also tried reinstalling virtualbox and genymotion but it didn't solve the problem.

Here's my log file: http://pastebin.com/CsdCJAw3 (I posted it in pastebin because it exceeds the characters limit here)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Are you running a VPN client like Cisco Any Connect. I was running it and Genymotion was continuously showing me the same issue. I just had to stop the VPN and close the VPN app if any. 
Restart Genymotion and voila it connected.
You can start your VPN after that and it should work.

In case it still doesn't work. After stopping the VPN or if you're not running the VPN client before starting Genymotion try running this command.
This used to help me when something was causing an issue with the virtual box daemon.

sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart

Comment: I'm not using any VPN, I also tried to restart the box daemon but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: checked your logs, there's some issue related to Host Only interface. You should delete all of the Host Only Interface and let Genymotion create one again for you. Hopefully this should help you.
https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#remove-hostonly

Comment: I tried that, and I completelly removing VirtualBox and reinstalling but it still doesn't work. Finally, I installed it in a Debian PC and all works fine. Thank you for your help